# Missing Activity & Fragment+ViewModel template

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack

I'm trying to get started with JetPack and MVVM and follows this tutorial : 
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/getting-started

It states I should pick the following activity template :

[image]

**Problem is I do not have it** :

[image]

I did download the latest android studio version (Canary 3.3), I Invalidated and restarted, downloaded latest SDK, but without sucess.

Comment: I think it's not yet officially launched, You might want to wait for some more time to be available for download. IMO.

Comment: Pic 1 is from 3.2 version and Pic 2 is from 3.3 version. Go with the Android Studio 3.2 version to get Activity & Fragment + ViewModel template

Comment: @Srikar Reddy You are right. Is it weird tho that the template disappeared in a newer version ? Did they decide to rollback ?

Comment: It is still missing in the released AS 3.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using android studio 3.2 stable version, and I couldn't also find "Activity & Fragment+ViewModel". But I had an option called "Fragment+ViewModel" and that generates the activity also along with the required fragment and viewmodel.

[image]

These are the generated files.

[image]

Comment: Android version is the answer

Comment: @SebastienFERRAND Yes, as you said  "android version" is the answer :-)

Comment: @SebastienFERRAND What do you mean by "Android version is the answer"?

Comment: @authentictech I just meant that Activity&Fragment+ViewModel was only in earlier versions of android studio. It was available as Fragment+ViewModel in version 3.2 and as I check-in version 3.3(stable) that option also is missing.

Comment: @SonuSanjeev thanks. I see Fragment+ViewModel in AndroidStudio 3.3 under the New > Activity menu and it looks to be the same thing as Activity & Fragment+ViewModel. I suppose they thought using the words "Activity &..." in the submenu item was redundant since it is implied in the Activity supermenu.

Answer (score 2):

in studio3.3 you can find  Fragment+ViewModel in this version
the position is **File->New->Activity->Fragment+ViewModel**

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 3.2 stable version we having those features. Please update your stable version to 3.2 and then start the MVVM pattern development. Congrats for success in advance.

Comment: My Android Studio is updated on latest stable version that is 3.2 but still it's not showing. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the "Create New Project" anymore but they already included Navigation Editor in Version 3.3.2

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#nav-editor